# Spring Cloud Config Server serving nested plain text files

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, configserver

I have a Config Server up and running, with the relevant application.yml setting of

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config
    ...
      searchPaths:
        - '{application}'
        - '{application}/{profile}'
```

I would like to access a file that is not `application.properties`, something like `myfile.txt`. If I have the git layout

```
/myapp/nested/folder/myfile.txt
```

I want to be able to access that file. According to [the Spring Config Server docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_plain_text.html), I should be able to do this via `/{name}/{profile}/{label}/{path}`, but I can't get any paths to work.

TL;DR: How do I retrieve nested config files from a git repo via Config Server?

Comment: Try with slashes rather than `(_)`?

Comment: [The docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html) specifically call out using `(_)` in place of `/` so that the delineations between `{label}` and `{application}` and etc. are parseable. I'll add those tries anyway to show they don't wok.

Comment: They are only for the placeholders in configuration, not the path of the file api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: The documentation is wrong. The endpoint `/{name}/{profile}/{label}/{path}` should be written as `/{application}/{profile}/{label}/{path}`. You just need to make sure that one of your `searchPaths/{path}` can resolve your file.

---

First off, `{label}` is, as always, the git branch name (probably "master").

Second, `{path}` can can be an absolute path to the file. It uses `/`, i.e., `myapp/nested/folder/myfile.txt`, not `(_)` as is required in `{application}` or `{label}`.

Third, the search paths in the question are set to  `'{application}'` and `'{application}/{profile}'`, along with the default search path of `/`, the git repo's root directory. These define the places Config Server will search for a plain text file as:

```
/{expanded application}/{path}
/{expanded application}/{profile}/{path}
/{path}
```

Note that only `{application}` can be expanded into multiple folders with `(_)` and that only `{path}` can include multiple folders with `/`. For instance, with these `searchPaths` and a file located at `/myapp/nested/folder/myfile.txt`, the following requests are valid:

```
/asdf/asdf/master/myapp/nested/folder/myfile.txt
/myapp/asdf/master/nested/folder/myfile.txt
/myapp/nested/master/folder/myfile.txt
/myapp(_)nested(_)folder/asdf/master/myfile.txt
/myapp(_)nested/folder/master/myfile.txt
```

where `asdf` can be any arbitrary string.

Comment: I can certainly create a config server and specifiy a path like this `http://localhost:8888/foo/default/master/nested/hello.txt` that correctly gets files in a directory.

Comment: It looks like you're right. It is possible to have a full path specified using `/`. I wish this were documented anywhere on that "serving plain text files" page instead of only having top-level files.

Comment: Edited my answer, thanks for the help. I'd like to do that! hopefully I'll get to it sometime this week.

Comment: I think the `{name}` field is wrong, since it is being mapped to `{application}` in the `searchPaths` I set, and is called `{application}` everywhere else in the documentation. The other parts were just unclear as there was no example with a nested filepath.